# Corrupt or Invalid JAR file

Tags: java, selenium

I have created a JAR file using Eclipse Neon.   I have done this before for this same project with no issue but for some reason now it is not able to run.   The size of the JAR file before would end up being 11,597,123+KB but now it is only 12,226 KB.   I am not sure what changed.   I am attaching a link to a screen recording to show what I am doing.    http://screencast.com/t/DAERIVpv9

Comment: A valid JAR file is also a valid ZIP file, you can try opening both in WinZip or such to see what's different.

Comment: Try selecting "Runnable Jar File".

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is the file? The name of the file was ``vtsregression_1` and you tried to run `vtsregression1` without underscore.

Comment: I have tried all methods to run even using the regular vtsregression.jar file with the same result.  I was merely giving them different names to try to keep track of what I was doing.   I have changed it to a zip file to see what is in there but am not sure what I need to look for.   Like I said I just did this the other day and it worked fine.   I am curious to know why the file size got so small.

Comment: I am getting closer but now I am getting this:C:\Users\Janet\Documents>java -cp /Users/Janet/workspace/RegressionTests/bin; -jar vtsregression_regular.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException

Comment: @Vlad Here is what is in the .classpath in the jar file: ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="RegressionTests"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
 <classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/Janet/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue although I do not know what was causing all of the previous problems finally exporting as an executable jar file worked.

Thanks for the help and direction pointing it really helped.